# Vegan/vegetarian diets during pregnancy dataset for master thesis

Tags: data-request, data

Does anyone know of the existence of a dataset about pregnancy and vegan or vegetarian diets? I would like to write a master thesis about the impact of a vegan or vegetarian diet on birth outcomes but l'm having difficulties in finding relevant data.